# Amaretta's birthday is July 27, and her brother Enzo's birthday is September 3. Every year, Amaretta and Enzo celebrate by eating cake

Tags: arithmetic

Amaretta's birthday is July 27, and her brother Enzo's birthday is September 3. Every year, Amaretta and Enzo celebrate by eating cake every day from Amaretta's birthday through Enzo's birthday (including both birthdays). If they did this for the first time in 2008, how many cake-eating days will they have observed by the end of 2016?

5 days in july
31 days is august
3 days in septemeber
39 days of cake eating per year
9 years from 2008 to 2016.
Assuming they aren't dead from all the cake or have diabetes, then 39*9=351 days of eating cake.

Does this make sense?

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: This does require the knowledge that you correctly determined: how many days there are in the affected months, and what months are involved.  (As Ross's answer alludes to, this question would have had a different answer if it read, "they ate cake until the day that Enzo got sick on September 3.  On that day, and on any later date, he was unable to eat cake.")  Small phrasing details can affect whether to count both ends, so this isn't just number-handling, but is a case of applying mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct.  The point of the problem is to avoid a [fencepost error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error) by counting both ends of the spans.